# How to read pipeline template parameters from generated pipeline job using a Jenkinsfile

Tags: templates, parameters, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have a pipeline built around a Jenkinsfile and a shared library. Everything works fine when using the Jenkinsfile from a standard parameterized pipeline job. I can easily read all the provided parameters from the environment in my Jenkinsfile script.

Now I need a template version of this pipeline so I can generate multiple pre-configured pipelines for different projects. The template contains a lot of 'Attributes', the same as the standard pipeline parameters, a link to the repository having the Jenkinsfile (Pipeline script from SCM), and a transformer of type 'Groovy template for Pipeline' where I set a basic XML configuration like this:

```
<flow-definition>
    <actions/>
    <properties>...</properties>
    <definition class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowDefinition">
        <spec/>
    </definition>
    <triggers>...</triggers>
</flow-definition>
```

When I create a new pipeline using this template, I can enter a value for all the template attributes. The result is a non-parameterized pipeline job where I can clearly see all the specified values in the 'Configure' option page, or from the config.xml:

```
<flow-definition>
    <actions>
        ...
    </actions>
    <properties>
        <com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.modeling.impl.jobTemplate.JobPropertyImpl plugin="cloudbees-template@4.59">
            <instance>
                <model>...</model>
                <values class="tree-map">
                    <entry>
                        <string>PARAM1</string>
                        <string>VALUE1</string>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <string>PARAM2</string>
                        <string>VALUE2</string>
                    </entry>
                    ...
                </values>
            </instance>
        </com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.modeling.impl.jobTemplate.JobPropertyImpl>
        ...
    </properties>
    ...
</flow-definition>
```

The problem starts here because when I launch this new generated pipeline, the environment doesn't get populated with the attributes of the job. I tried many sources, but I've never been able to get my values yet. There must be something I'm missing. And when searching about problems with pipeline parameters, 95% of the results are for parameterized pipeline, which is not my case.

I tried to read values from all these sources:

```
    env.getEnvironment()
    params
    properties.binding
    getBinding().variables
    currentBuild.getBuildVariables
```

In my original parameterized pipeline, I can simply read parameters using `env.PARAM1` or `"${PARAM1}"`, so I assume that I should be able to do the same with my generated Job. I started thinking that the template attributes were only available when parsing the transformation XML, but what kind of XML instruction should I create in my template flow-definition to set the runtime environment of the generated job? The only example I got about adding parameters to the flow-definition was adding ParametersDefinitionProperty with a parameterDefinitions block, but this adds UI parameters to the generated pipeline job which makes it a parameterized pipeline, and that's not what I want.

Any idea?

EDIT: I can get attributes value from the environment only from Jenkinsfile directly.

`println "$env.PARAM1"` in the Jenkinsfile works, but from a Groovy in the shared library, it returns null. So the only workable solution for now is to manually transfert all my attributes to the environment before calling the shared library methods.

**Jenkinsfile**

```
env['PARAM1'] = "$PARAM1"
env['PARAM2'] = "$PARAM2"
...
MyPipelineLauncherFunction(...)
```

That's really ugly, but it works.